# Insertar datos de un dataframe a postgres con python

Tags: python, postgresql, dataframe

Estoy intentando insertar datos de un Dataframe a postgres, pero no me inserta nada ni me indica errores de ejecución.
mi código:

```
dataframe = extraerLimpiarComunidades()
    for index, row in dataframe.iterrows():
        print(row.Id)
        print(row.Comunidad)
        cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO comunidades (id,nombre) values (?,?)''',
                       (row.Id,row.Comunidad))
```

Los print los he puesto para ver que recorre correctamente el dataframe, y me los muestra bien.
Pero al ejecutar la query no inserta los valores en la tabla.
Agradezco la ayuda.

Comment: Creo que en vez de `(?, ?)` debe ir `(%s, %s)`.

Comment: Confirmo lo que dice Abulafia!

Comment: Antes de preguntar por aquí lo probé, porque lo vi así también en ejemplos. Pero a mi no me funciona así. @abulafia

Comment: Pues tendrás que dar más detalles de por qué dices que no te funciona, porque en principio sería lo correcto. ¿Te da errores? ¿excepciones? ¿no ocurre nada como con `(?,?)` ?

Comment: Pues la cosa es que no me da ningún error, me hace lo mismo que de la otra forma. Termina la ejecución sin generar excepciones y en la BBDD no hay ningún dato insertado. @abulafia

Comment: ¿Cómo incializas `cursor`? Lo típico es tener un bloque `with connection.cursor() as cursor:` y dentro de él hacer el  (o los) `cursor.execute()`. De ese modo al terminar ese bloque se cierra la conexión y te aseguras de que los comandos SQL son enviados.

Comment: @abulafia, yo lo que hago es crear la conexion dentro de un try, desde ahí creo la tabla y lanzo el insert hacia esa tabla. Tengo un except y si algo sale mal entra ahí. Y si va todo bien o algo sale mal tengo el finally para cerrar la conexion y cursor

Comment: @abulafia, he logrado introducir los datos.  Muchas gracias por la ayuda. Me he fijado en este articulo que viene bastante bien explicado:  https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/examples.html